# Raspberry pi web server

Tags: raspberry-pi3

I've been trying to set up my own web server with the raspberry pi3 b+ and it was going good so far i could made a ddns and access it from any other wifi or anything, the only problem was that i couldn't change the default "Debian apache" site.

I googled a lot about it and everybody said that all i have to do is change the root directory /var/www/to my directory but i just couldn't save the files, as it asked me if I wanna overwrite it - I pressed yes but it told me that I don't have permission for that I also couldn't overwrite the index.html file that was in the default folder. Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: You might need `sudo`.

Comment: I do have sudo I used it at every step but I couldn't overwrite the files with them too

Comment: i recommend nginx over apache. Also you might want to setup a bind9 dns server to access the ip with much ease.

Comment: Do you think nginx is better than apache?I'm asking it because I'm pretty much a beginner, and I wonder if i will be able to edit the index.html file as I asked before. I'll definitely try this method when I have time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Dkrisztan personally I used both. I started with apache like 10 yrs back and moved to nginx just because of the format on configuration files in nginx. They are super easy to understand compared to apache in some ways. You can control everything about nginx via /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and add additional conf files in /etc/nginx/conf.d/ folder for virtual hosts or reverse proxy setup.

Comment: @nuke1010 Hey, thanks a lot. I eventually learned to control apache2 now, the only issue I'm having right now is making my local server public.I posted a question about it not so long ago. Really appreciate the answer to my previous question tho :)).

Comment: @Dkrisztan sure

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while doing this myself. You need to open terminal from the Raspberry Pi, or SSH. You need to change the folder type to 755, which allows the user to read,write,execute. Make sure that the directory you do this to is the /var/www/html folder. 
All you need to do is type:

```
chmod -R 755  (dir)
```

dir = directory of the file.
If you'd like to change a file, such as the default index.html file in there, use 744 instead of 755.
After this, if you want to start the server, just type in
`sudo service apache2 start`
Here's a link for how to install the apache2 package.
https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-web-server/

Comment: @ankabout not too sure what you mean. Please explain so i can edit my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I mean that advising to set 777 could be a security breach, it is better to set 755 for folders and 744 for files and set the owner of the folders/files to the 'relevant' user.

Comment: I think you should also put the command that changes the file/dir owner, `chown -R (user) (dir)`. Anyway hope it solves the OP problem.